# SQL server how stop process run from xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, cmd, kill-process, taskmanager, xp-cmdshell

i try open folder from my computer
by run script in sql server

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'start C:\folder'
```

it folder not exixt and the process still execute
then i do kill process

but it still KILLED/ROLLBACK

what to do now?

help!!
michal

Comment: If the external process (external to SQL Server) suddenly stops and does not correctly return execution to SQL Server and you try to kill the SQL Server process, then you will see this `KILLED/ROLLBACK` status and won't be able to remove this process from SQL Server until server restart, unfortunately. Good news is that nothing is actually executing, so you won't lose CPU time. That being said, it's not recommended to start cmd processes through SQL Server due to security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open cmd:

`tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /fi "SESSIONNAME eq Services" /v`

get the PID of the running session (assuming it is 123456)

`taskkill /PID 123456 /F`

Comment: Iptr - thank you !!
I did And that did solve the problem
Just a question how do I know that this is exactly the CMD I run and not anyone that connected to the server or the SQL server itself can run? In short is it dangerous to stop it?

Comment: you could check the command line of the process (eg. 123456)  to be killed and verify that the parent process is sqlserver :  `wmic process where "ProcessID=123456"  get CommandLine, ParentPocessID`   (assuming ParentProcessID=45678) `wmic process where "ProcessID=45678"  get Name`